# How to do export import work in inertaijs react laravel 10 project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

Laravel 10 Import Export Excel & CSV File Example with inertiajs react export not working.

how can i fixed it. please help me.

Give me some suggestion how I can do it.

This project laravel 10 use in inertiajs react.

please help me......